# Copying Column D to Column A Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy

So the problem is that I wanna copy a filtered sheet, this means that Columns A,B,C are gone so it starts at D. When copying using this bit op code it will copy it to Column D again but I need it to reorganize itself and copy to Column A in a new sheet.

Thanks in advance!

```
Option Explicit
Sub Copy()
Dim rng As Range
Sheets.Add.Name = "TEST2"
Set rng = "Worksheets("TESTSHEET".Range("A1:ZZ1000")
Worksheets("TEST2").Range("A1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: There are only two things. What is the `Source Range Address` and what is the `Destination First Cell Address`? Could you clarify what *Columns A,B,C are gone* means? Are they hidden or you just don't want them copied? Btw, an obvious mistake is in `Set rng = "Worksheets("TESTSHEET".Range("A1:ZZ1000")` which should be `Set rng = Worksheets("TESTSHEET").Range("A1:ZZ1000")`